# Combining Regular Expressions with Vectors for Text Substitution in R

Tags: r, regex, vectorization, sapply, grepl

I have a dataframe with a column of track titles, artists, and music genres I scraped from Spotify. In R for reproducibility:

```
a <- c("Run the World (Girls)", "LOCO", "Habits", "Never Born - 2017 Version")
b <- c("Beyoncé", "NERVO", "Marmozets", "Guano Apes")
c <- c("dance pop pop post-teen pop r&b", "australian dance big room deep big room edm electro house house progressive electro house progressive house", "alt-indie rock british alternative rock pixie", "alternative metal funk metal nu metal post-grunge rap metal rap rock")
df <- data.frame(SONG=a, ARTIST=b, GENRE=c)
```

EDITED TO INCLUDE THE ACTUAL TABULAR INPUT AND DESIRED OUTPUT.

This is the input dataframe as described above.
[image: Original Dataframe]

I want to clean up the genres for analyses. For the time being I have created a list of common genres:

```
main_genres <- c("hip hop", "pop", "country", "latin", "dance", "rock", "classical", "jazz", "indie", "folk", "metal", "reggae", "punk")
```

I've created a new data frame for what I'd ultimately like to do.

```
all_main_genres <- data.frame(TRACK = character(), ARTIST = character(), GENRE = character())
```

What I'd like to know is if there is a non-loop way to search the `GENRE` column of `df` for ANY and ALL the strings in the `main_genres` vector and, if so, to create a new row in `all_main_genres` that includes the original song title and song artist, and in the new `GENRE` column, the **MATCHED** genre from `main_genres`.

So for example, the first row in `all_main_genres` will be

TRACK = Run the World (Girls)

ARTIST = Beyoncé

GENRE = dance

This is because the first row of `GENRE` in `df` matches both "dance" and "pop" from the `main_genres` vector. Because there are two matches, the second row of `all_main_genres` will be:

TRACK = Run the World (Girls)

ARTIST = Beyoncé

GENRE = pop

And then the third row will be NERVOs song with the genre as **dance** and the third will be the Marmozets song with the genre as **indie** then the Marmozets song with genre **rock** etc.

In other words it should look like this:
[image: Desired dataframe]

I used `sapply` with `grepl`

```
sapply(main_genres, grepl, playlist_genres$GENRE[row], ignore.case = TRUE)
```

And the vector matching works but I'm not sure how to extend this to `gsub` with a vector of potential substitutions which will themselves act as what is substituted.
Haven't seen this with vectors yet so please forgive if it's a repost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be helpful to show input and output in tabular form.  I don't completely follow your logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I apologize for the clarity issue. Do the images I added help or is there other information I can provide/clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df%>%
     tidytext::unnest_tokens(GENRE,GENRE,stringr::str_extract_all,pattern=glue::collapse(main_genres,"|"))%>%
     unique%>%
     `rownames<-`(NULL)
                       SONG     ARTIST GENRE
1     Run the World (Girls)    Beyoncé dance
2     Run the World (Girls)    Beyoncé   pop
3                      LOCO      NERVO dance
4                    Habits  Marmozets indie
5                    Habits  Marmozets  rock
6 Never Born - 2017 Version Guano Apes metal
7 Never Born - 2017 Version Guano Apes  rock
```

To do this in base R: you would do:

```
GENRE=regmatches(df$GENRE,gregexpr(paste(main_genres,collapse = "|"),df$GENRE))
unique(transform(df[rep(1:nrow(df),lengths(GENRE)),1:2],GENRE=unlist(GENRE),row.names=NULL))
                        SONG     ARTIST GENRE
1      Run the World (Girls)    Beyoncé dance
2      Run the World (Girls)    Beyoncé   pop
5                       LOCO      NERVO dance
6                     Habits  Marmozets indie
7                     Habits  Marmozets  rock
9  Never Born - 2017 Version Guano Apes metal
13 Never Born - 2017 Version Guano Apes  rock
```

Comment: This absolutely does it! I didn't even have tidytext installed so I never would have thought of this in a million years. I do play on doing text mining in the future so I'm so glad you lead me in this direction although at the current point in time I have no idea how this command actually works. 
Thanks for your time and your help!

Comment: Oh you can use tidyverse only.. `transform(df,GENRE=regmatches(GENRE,gregexpr(paste(main_genres,collapse = "|"),GENRE)))%>%
  tidyr::unnest()%>%unique()` or even `df%>%dplyr::mutate(GENRE=stringr::str_extract_all(GENRE,paste(main_genres,collapse = "|")))%>%
 tidyr::unnest()%>%unique()` etc etc